Why failing to unload com.apple.sharingd.plist with launchctl nor with sudo nor with root?
[MacOS Monterey 12.7] 
sharingd looks related with a weird window flash popup on desktop right after booting. As I researched, this daemon has to do with services that I don't need (AirDrop, Handoff, Instant Hotspot, Shared Computers, and Remote Disc). At the same time when explored this daemon: 
launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.sharingd 
...
    path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sharingd.plist
    state = running

    program = /usr/libexec/sharingd
    inherited environment = {
        DISPLAY => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.NycH5eDM3b/org.xquartz:0
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9u8d0kZoxg/Listeners
    }
...
    properties = keepalive | runatload | supports transactions | system service | exponential throttling
...

Two weird sockets that at the same time I am not capable to explore/guess what are their functions.
Those are the reasons I wanted to unload this plist:
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sharingd.plist

I had no problem unloading other plists (i.e. an Epson printer daemon that surfaced with nmap listening in a port), but when I try with this one, this happens (tried with normal, sudo, root. Everything) [And this plist is not present in LaunchDaemons folder, just in LaunchAgents]:
Nor with unload
Library root# sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sharingd.plist
Warning: Expecting a LaunchDaemons path since the command was ran as root. Got LaunchAgents instead.
`launchctl bootout` is a recommended alternative.
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
Try running `launchctl bootout` as root for richer errors. 

Nor with bootout
Library root# sudo launchctl bootout /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sharingd.plist
Unrecognized target specifier.
Usage: launchctl bootout <domain-target> [service-path1, service-path2, ...] | <service-target>
<service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Library root# 

This Listeners thing, happens to be a socket (I have no experience at all with sockets). So any attemp to explore it in a file fashion way, failed.
% cd /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9u8d0kZoxg/         
% ls
Listeners
% ls -lrt
total 0
srw-rw-rw-  1 myhost  wheel  0  2 abr 09:05 Listeners
% cat Listeners 
cat: ai_family not supported: Undefined error: 0
cat: Listeners: Invalid argument
% less Listeners 
Listeners is not a regular file (use -f to see it)
% less -f Listeners
Listeners: Operation not supported on socket

Poping window on startup  (snapshot is from Internet, but is same as mine. Other users experienced this): 


Please [edit] your post with a clear description of the issue and why you think unloading a plist will solve it.

sharingd does not create “weird window popups;”. You also didn’t show which sockets it was bound to…you provided environment variables.  To be candid, the whole post is rife with syntactical errors (not grammar, but usage) that indicates you’re quite new at this. Before tinkering with daemons, boot into Safe Mode (diagnostics mode) and see if you still get the problem.  Also create a temp user, login to that account and see if the popup remains.  Let’s start there

Mr. @Allan can you help me in some way? I think you are beyond capable of understanding what are my concerns about all this. From your words I infere that sharingd is a totally harmless process and does not need to be cancelled?  Even if you are not using all those services? Even more, have dependencies that are not good to tweak with?

A huge and welcomed start, would be how to do this:  "You also didn’t show which sockets it was bound to…". How can I do that?

"Also create a temp user, login to that account and see if the popup remains. Let’s start there". Ok, this will be another starting path. But I am very interested in this: >> "You also didn’t show which sockets it was bound to…". How can I do this?

BTW What is your serious and sincere guessing/opinion about this two things: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.NycH5eDM3b/org.xquartz:0
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9u8d0kZoxg/Listeners

They are environment variables.  The fist one is which display things are rendered and the second defines the temp sockets it will listen on

"and see if you still get the problem." My problem is not "popping windows" due to aesthetic discomfort. My question grows from the reasoning that a legitimate process should not need a flashing popping window because presumably well designed would grant permissions in the background or if user permission needed, would appear and stay until some click would be done. Agree?

That screen is a privacy and security (one time) question whether you want mediasharingd, a totally different daemon from the one you’re tinkering with, to have network access.  There’s no need to unload any plist as there’s no problem.  Just allow network access as its a legit and safe process.

@Allan So you are saying that those path/files are "environmental variables"? For the program to look for things? And just for the XQuartz (X Windows Server for MacOs)? The two of them? "Listeners" also? (I mean xquartz, very likely, but that "Listeners" too?

@Allan Ok, with sharingd. But very direct question: how the... Firewall? Just flashes a window in milliseconds to grant or not mediasharingd and even more: why does not remember (I remember I could granted [exhausted] with 'Allow' a couple of years ago during a lagging boot, enough to click on it) the rule for the following bootings? (Or even with the previous "Deny"s. Why the rule was not remembered by the firewall so the popping was never again?). –

(BTW, I am very aware about the avoid chatting thing on comments). But after your explanations I think I am starting to understand... This plist snippet shows the settings sharingd relies on... So there is no mystery nor strange things there... They are simply, like places for sharingd to put and to get things... (Like when lscommand needs the /binpath to work, for example. Or the stdoutto show things on shell). I understand.

So here comes the question: how can I end/kill that popping window thing from mediasharingd (if it's a bad or a not necessary thing. If it's good, I would obviously leave it) and, please if you don't mind, also some extra words/explanation on the "legitimate flashing popping windows", because I still don't get the point.

(Should I post a new question with this previous comment or am I able to let it be in this comments thread in the context of this post/question? I don't mind deleting all the post and redoing a new with this last question. Or keeping it and posting another one. But I think all this can be very helpful for other people. I will do whatever is better on the rules and the community. Thx)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
